# Javascript movement on key hold

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, addeventlistener, keydown

I need help with a movement function for a canvas game.

Below is what I have, and what happens is the player only changes direction when a left/right key is pressed.

It would be ideal for the player to face the corresponding direction from holding down either the left or right arrow keys, which currently doesn't occur.

I have no idea how to do this, any ideas?

I now have movement direction working on key hold down, updated below, but when the page first loads, the player is not displayed on the screen, but then displays after a key is pressed. Something is not right...

```js
var trackRight = 0;
var trackLeft = 1;
var x = 570;
var y = 255; //no collision past here
var srcX;
var srcY;
var speed = 25;

var character = new Image();
character.src = "ptera_purple.png";

function updateFrame() {
    curFrame = ++curFrame % frameCount;
    srcX = curFrame * width;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, x, y, width, height);


    if (left && x > 0) {
        srcY = trackLeft * height; //important for sprite direction
        x -= speed;
    }

    if (right && x < canvasWidth - width) {
        srcY = trackRight * height;
        x += speed;
    }
}

var right = false;
var left = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        right = true;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        left = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        right = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        left = false;
    }
}

function moveLeft() { // keyboard controls
    left = true;
    right = false;
}

function moveRight() {
    left = false;
    right = true;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? It seems to me that the key handlers are the least important part of the problem here; there must be another function that tests the `right` and `left` variables in order to update the state/velocity/direction/whatever of the player?

Comment: @nnnnnn, added the rest. Theres both keyboard movement and arrow key movement, you think this will be clashing?

Answer (score 2):

### Depreciated `keyEvent.keyCode` do not use.

Please note that `keyEvent.keyCode` has been depreciated and should not be used. You can use `keyEvent.key` or `keyEvent.code` where `key` is what the user intends to see (holds shift or capslock for "A", or not for "a") and `code` is for the key location where code is always 'KeyA' no matter if capital or not.

[MDN keyboardevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) for full details

**Use a keyState object**

The easiest way I have found to use the keyboard in animations and games is to have a object of key states. Add the same simple event to both down and up

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyhandler);
document.addEventListener("keyup",keyhandler);
```

Create key state object

```
var keyState = {};
```

And then just flag the key depending on the input event

```
function keyHandler(e){  // simple but powerful
   keyState[e.code] = e.type === "keydown";
}
```

Then in the main loop all you have to do to know if a key is down

```
if(keyState.ArrowRight) { // right  is down }
if(keyState.LeftRight) { // left  is down }
```

**Detailed state**

Never do any input processing in IO events when you have a running loop..

You can get more info. I usually have a toggle, and a state change

```
keyState = {
   down : {},   // True if key is down
   toggle : {},  // toggles on key up
   changed : {},  // True if key state changes. Does not set back false
                 // or you will lose a change
} 

function keyHandler(e){  // simple but powerful
   if(keyState.down[e.code] !== (e.type === "keydown")){
       keyState.changed = true;
   }
   keyState.down[e.code] = e.type === "keydown";
   if(e.type === "keyup"){
       keyState.toggle[e.code] = !keyState.toggle[e.code];
   }
}
```

Now if you want to know if a key has just been pressed

```
 if(keyState.down.LeftArrow && keyState.changed.LeftArrow){
      // key has been pushed down since last time we checked.
 }
 keyState.changed.LeftArrow = false; // Clear it  so we can detect next change
```

Comment: Deprecated not depreciated ;-( even if in my mother tongue the former would be more understood as not liked anymore, which still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a global event listen and track the pressdown then save the movement somewhere. Check what i've done here https://github.com/panvourtsis/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON-/blob/master/canvas.pokemon.js

Also check this

```
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        if(e.keyCode == "37") console.log("left");
        else if(e.keyCode == "38") console.log("up");
        else if(e.keyCode == "39") console.log("right");
        else if(e.keyCode == "40") console.log("down");
    };
```

Comment: I have key hold down movement now. Atm, the player from the start of page load does not show. This is fixed when the player moves. Just have to work out now why this is happening.

Comment: you must draw it initially with some x and y and the start moving him from that initial point

Answer (score 0):

you can add a while loop:

```
while(left == true) {
//code to execute
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work but you can try it.

Comment: That **will not work** and will block the page. No event can fire while code is executing and thus when left is true the while loop will loop forever.