# keypress event listener producing inconsistent motion in processing.js

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I use the keypress event listener in a lot of animations in processing js and here is a problem that consistently plagues me. In this example I made, when I press the 'd' button, a ball moves to the right. Actually, the ball is stationary, and the ground moves left below it.

The problem is this: When I press and hold 'd', the ball lurches right at the correct speed almost instantly, but then stops for an instant, then reaches the correct speed and then continues at that speed for as long as I hold 'd'. I don't know why the ball doesn't hit that speed and stay there, but that is what I'd like it to do.

Here is a fiddle which may show what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/4s14wq4d/

The method is quite simple:

```
hill.prototype.moveRight = function() {
  this.x -= 5;
};
```

And here is the event listener in action:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
myCanvas.addEventListener("keypress", functionMove);
function functionMove(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "100") {
    for (var i = 0; i < hillArray.length; i++) {
      hillArray[i].moveRight();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You might want to work with keyup and keydown instead, take a look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448981/remove-keydown-delay-in-javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952551/javascript-movement-on-key-hold

Comment: I'm not sure why using 'keyup' and 'keydown' is making this thing unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should not be adding your own event listeners. Processing gives you functions like `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()`. Use those instead.

Secondly, what you probably want to do is create variables that keep track of whether a key is pressed or not. Something like this:

```
var wPressed = false;
var sPressed = false;
var aPressed = false;
var dPressed = false;
```

Then in the `keyPressed()`  function, you would set the corresponding variable to `true`, and in the `keyReleased()` function, you'd set it to `false`.

Finally, in the `draw()` function, you'd check each of the variable and do the right thing. Something like this:

```
if(dPressed){
   for (var i = 0; i < hillArray.length; i++) {
     hillArray[i].moveRight();
   }
}
```

(Side note: If you're moving all of the elements by the same distance, you might just want to use a single `xOffset` variable or something that you use, that way you don't have to loop over every item to move it individually.)

Shameless self promotion: I wrote a tutorial on user input (including the above approach) available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). It's for regular Processing, but all of the ideas are the same in Processing.js.

Comment: I'll look into functions you've mentioned and try to understand what functionality I've been doing without. as for the sidenote, I'm assuming looping the hills to move them slows the animation? Or is it (also) an aesthetic thing, too? My basics are patchy so the more content I can examine the better so I'll check out the link you provided.

Comment: Unless you're talking about thousands of individual objects, you probably won't notice any difference in animation speed. After all, you have to loop through all of the objects to draw them anyway. It's more of a "don't do work you don't have to do" principle. They'll all have the same offset, so it's easier to change one number instead of 100 numbers. But honestly you should go with whatever makes sense in your brain.

Comment: I tried the boolean variable keyPressed in an if statement and it doesn't seem to work. In a previous post, you called what I was using "instance mode". To the best that I can tell, I'm writing my animations in javascript and they're being translated into processing. Is that right? At any rate, when I tried writing the same line of code 'if (keyPressed && key == 'd') {move something}' in a chunk of code I wrote in processing, it worked just fine. Part of the reason I used my own event listeners was because I couldn't get sthing like key/mousePressed.

Comment: @Jozurcrunch I'm not recommending that you use the `keyPressed` variable. I'm recommending that you use the `keyPressed()` function. And you've got it reversed: Processing.js usually works by translating Processing code into JavaScript, and then using a JavaScript library. What you're doing is just using the JavaScript library directly, skipping the translation step. I'd be happy to continue helping, but please post any follow-up questions in a new question post with an updated [mcve]. Good luck.

Comment: Great. I used keyPressed along with a boolean and the motion is now smooth. I'm not sure at all why the way I had it before produced that lag, but for now this solves my problem.

Comment: @Jozurcrunch It created the lag because the OS determines when a key is pressed. Just go into a text editor and hold down a key. Notice that you'll get one character right away, then a slight pause, then a bunch of characters. That's exactly what's supposed to happen.